# How to split repeating pattern?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that repeats a pattern. I have a regular expression that matches the pattern, but I would like to split them instead.

```
$target = 'a1v33a33v55a2v43';
```

I would like to split them into a1v33, a33v55, and a2v43. Basically, I want to split the string into an array of ['a1v33', 'a33v55', 'a2v43'].

I've tried the following code, but it only matches the pattern. How can I split them instead?

```
$target = 'a1v33a33v55a2v43';
$pattern = '/(a[0-9]+v[0-9]+)*$/im';

preg_match($pattern, $target, $match);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($match);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `preg_split` too:

```
$result = preg_split('~(?=a)~i', $target, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: I like this one because of its simple elegance - chapeau :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `preg_match_all` with `'/a[0-9]+v[0-9]+/i'`:

```
$target = 'a1v33a33v55a2v43';
$pattern = '/a[0-9]+v[0-9]+/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $target, $match);
print_r($match);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/LEzMMO)

The `/(a[0-9]+v[0-9]+)*$/im` pattern matches some substrings meeting `a[0-9]+v[0-9]+` pattern, 1 or more occurrences, up to the end of the string (`$`). When we remove the quantified grouping with the end-of-line/string anchor, we can match indiviual tokens.